# Running program with sleep vs schedule with task scheduler

Tags: windows, sleep, windows-server-2008-r2, task-scheduler

I have a Java-program that shall check if a value in the database has changed each minute. If the value has changed the program shall perform a task.

To run the program from cmd takes about 7 seconds when the program only checks the value in the database.

What is the best solution? To schedule the program with Task Scheduler each minute or have the program constantly running and sleeping for 1 minute between every check? Is the scheduling with Task Scheduler resource demanding?

The OS is Windows Server 2008R2.

Answer (score 0):

When you run it scheduled with the scheduler you are starting a new program instance every minute.
And the new program has to open and close the database every time.
This is more resource intensive on both the server and the database than a program that keeps running all the time and only polls the (already open) database connection once a minute to do it's check.
On the other hand... A continuously running program may slowly leak memory or other resources over time. And if the database for some reason goes offline/is unreachable while the program is running it must be able to recover from that. The scheduled program obviously doesn't have to deal with that.

You may have enough system performance that there is no noticeable difference no mater which variant you use.

So it really depends upon the entire environment. I can't make a general "best practice" recommendation.

Comment: I disagree. Task Scheduler induces a slowdown on tasks run. I had a script that starts Fraps to record gameplay to my harddrive. Because fraps requires administrative privileges and I got tired of always pressing OK, I used the start from task scheduler trick to automatically do it. Basically all task scheduler did was start the task and run as administrator. Once I did that, I experienced lag spikes in-game and it appeared task scheduler added a delay which simply made me abandon the whole task scheduler idea.

Comment: @LPChip That doesn't make sense. Whether a program is started by TaskScheduler or normally has no impact on its speed. It runs under exactly the same conditions. There must have been another contributing factor in your case.

Comment: I have tested it extensively and came to the conclusion that Task Scheduler really does create an overhead. The CPU usage for task scheduler went up the whole time the task was active even though the task itself was doing nothing.

Comment: I agree, normally it should not do so, but its quirky it seems, as many things in windows are. Also, I noticed that if you have many tasks in task scheduler, the tasks themselves can slow down too, even though none of the other tasks are running.

Comment: @LPChip I have seen a couple of cases where the anti-virus (observed with PC-Cillin/TrendMicro, Panda and Symantec) got really paranoid about scheduled tasks and kept very aggressively re-scanning them which slowed down everything. Maybe that was also happening in your case?

Comment: No it wasn't. I have tested it at various places, different machines, different OSes, it happened in each and every instance. Some were more noticeable than others, but in every instance I did see at least some slowdown compared to the same situation without task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I know from my own experience that Task Scheduler impacts your system no matter what the script you run does. Task Scheduler works great to start a task in the background, but it will not run at full speed.

Task Scheduler itself creates overhead the more intensive its being used, and for that reason I strongly recommend not using task scheduler. Even if you would use task scheduler to only start the task once and the task then continuously calls itself, there will be overhead.

So instead, I would highly recommend to use a startup script to activate the loop, and perform the check every minute.

You may want to look into other ways to do this though, and you may want to check if a 5 minute interval is not a big compromise.

That value in the database is changed somewhere. Can't that process perform the action too, or initiate a script serverside?